# Swift app translation does not work with a string showing a var

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to translate my app but it is not currently working for a single line! Here's my code:

```
mailVC.setMessageBody(NSLocalizedString("Your Flight Hazard Index Score : \((totalScore as NSNumber).stringValue) <br /> <br />Canadian Helicopters Limited", comment: ""), isHTML: true)
```

and it is translated in localized.strings like this:

```
"Your Flight Hazard Index Score : \((totalScore as NSNumber).stringValue) <br /> <br />Canadian Helicopters Limited"="Votre Résultat d'évaluation du risque : \((totalScore as NSNumber).stringValue) <br /> <br />Hélicoptères Canadiens Limitée";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use something like this as a key. Use something like `mailBodyKey` as key then have the english as base in your localization

Comment: ?? could you explain what it is ?? how would I bring a function like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, for those who might need it one day,

what I've done is made a var containing all my strings, then added that var to my set.MessageBody. take a look :

```
var emailtext = NSLocalizedString("Your Flight Hazard Index Score : "), comment : "");
emailtext += "\(totalscore)";
// and so on...
```

and here is my set.MessageBody

```
mailVC.setMessageBody("\(emailtext)"), isHTML: true)
```

that way I'm able to add as many other values and var and strings I want to my email

thanks !